# How to unflatten properties, ignored in other map?

Tags: automapper

Sources for my destination are spitted in root dto and its child property:

```
public class Source {
    public AccountSource {get;set;}
    public string AccountKey {get;set;}
    public string AccountPassword {get;set;}
}

public class AccountSource {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Dest
{
    public Account Account { get; set; }

    public class Account
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
    }
}
```

At now I have such mapping:

```
CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
    .ForPath(x => x.Account.Id, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.Account.Id))
    .ForPath(x => x.Account.Name, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.Account.Name))
    .ForPath(x => x.Account.Key, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.AccountKey))
    .ForPath(x => x.Account.Password, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.AccountPassword));
CreateMap<AccountSource, Dest.Account>()
    .ForAllMembers(x => x.Ignore());
```

but it have one issue: new members added to `Dest.Account` will be not validated.

If remove `ForPath` and just leave

```
CreateMap<Source, Dest>();
CreateMap<AccountSource, Dest.Account>();
```

than Password and Key are Unmapped, so I have to Ignore() them in such way `CreateMap<AccountSource, Dest.Account>().ForMember(x => x.Password, x=> x.Ignore()).ForMember(x => x.Key, x=> x.Ignore())`.

But then unflattening not working (props ignored absolutely, not only when account→account mapping occurred).

Answer (score 1):

By default, ForPath will ignore Dest.Account, but you can always map it explicitly:

```
    CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
        .ForPath(d => d.Account.Key, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.AccountKey))
        .ForPath(d => d.Account.Password, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.AccountPassword))
        .ForMember(d => d.Account, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Account));
    CreateMap<AccountSource, Account>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Password, o => o.Ignore())
        .ForMember(d => d.Key, o => o.Ignore());
```

Comment: Can you please explain, why Id and Name not mapped without `.ForMember(d => d.Account, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Account))` (as I can see in execution plan)?

Comment: I already did. You're not using things as intended. ForPath by default will ignore Account, because otherwise Account might be unmapped.

Comment: Ok. However you solution still have the same issue. I.e. without `.ForPath(d => d.Account.Key` configuration still valid.

Comment: No, because Key is explicitly ignored. But other members will be validated.

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution:

```
CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Account, o => o.MapFrom(x => x));
CreateMap<Source, Dest.Account>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Id, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.AccountSource.Id))
    .ForMember(x => x.Name, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.AccountSource.Name))
    .ForMember(x => x.Password, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.AccountPassword))
    .ForMember(x => x.Key, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.AccountKey));
```